# When I click a link to another domain it opens in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

When I click a link to another domain, either from a website to another or when I search something on google and click a link, it opens the new link in a new tab. This is extremely annoying as then there are two tabs open and on the new tab I can't go back. I saw something which said to turn off "Open each selected result in a new browser window" in chrome search settings. However, after I click save it still happens and when I go back to settings I see that it hasn't saved and has ticked the box again. I also saw something else which said that it was a virus but I ran Malwarebytes and Adaware twice but both found no viruses. If anyone can help with this I will be extremely grateful.

Comment: do you have any extensions or scripts enabled? have you checked if this behavious persists while in incognito mode (which typically turns off all extensions)? have you disabled cookies (preventing search settings from saving your preferences)? Lastly, you can try creating a new Chrome profile and test if the behaviour persists. Tell us the results and maybe we can try a few more things

Comment: I have Adblock Plus, Honey and Grammarly. It doesn't happen in incognito. Blocking all cookies does fix the issue. Using another chrome profile does fix it. I changed back to blocking third-party cookies and cleared all my cookies and it's fixed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's started opening them in a new tab again for some reason. These are the cookies that are now there if that's important: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/615646436800987162/730179396316561438/unknown.png. When I cleared them it stopped doing it again so it must be one of these.